# SFTP access to different parts of the apache webroot for different users

Tags: permissions, sftp

I have a website running on apache with the web root folder at /var/www.

I have different people managing different aspects of the website.

- Designers accesses /var/www/images and /var/www/media
- Developers access /var/www/code
- A 3rd party outside contractor accesses /var/www/code/3rd_party_code.

The entire /var/www/ is owned by www-data as that is what apache is run as.

Is there any Linux users and/or grouping permission scheme I can use to make sure people are only able to change their parts of the website? Note also there is some overlap. For instance, developers can also see the 3rd party code. Also, designers access different folders (/var/www/images and /var/www/media) and chroot will not work (I think!).

Access will be only via SFTP. I will disable ssh shell access as necessary.
This is on Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS.

Comment: Can you not just use filesystem permissions & ACLs?

Comment: Yes, you can do this using extended ACL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like access control lists is exactly what I need. I will read up on this: [ACLS in Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs).
Thanks Andy and Jakuje.

Comment: @dr01 "Seems like access control lists is exactly what I need."